# Formatting TimeSpans

Tags: c#, exception, timespan, formatexception

I am trying to format a `TimeSpan` with the following line of code:

`.ToString("[d.]hh:mm:ss")`

It throws a `FormatException`, but the exception goes away when I remove the `:`, the `[]`, and the `.`. I also cannot include spaces. Does anyone know why this is happening? On [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ecy8h51%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) msdn page it clearly states that you can include these characters. I am using .Net framework 4.5.2 btw.

Thanks.

Comment: These characters have to be [escaped](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Other). By the way, do you really want square brackets around `d.` or are they only the result of copy-pasting the format string from MSDN?

Comment: I assumed the `[]` would mean that nothing inside them would render had the `d` element not been shown; I don't want a stranded `.`. There was nothing on the MSDN about escaping, plus I tried adding a `@` in front of the string and it still didn't work.

Comment: @TheGateKeeper That's not how you escape a character, that's a string literal.

Comment: I thought it automatically escaped all of the characters inside the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(5, 10, 44);
string test = string.Format("{0:dd\\:hh\\:mm\\:ss\\.ffff}", ts);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the literal characters.  It's quite awkward but this is what you need.

```
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(1, 2, 3, 4, 555);

string output = ts.ToString("d\\.hh\\:mm\\:ss");
```

See [Docs here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).