# VB.Net Formatting TimeSpan with .Net Framework 2.0

Tags: vb.net, string, frameworks, format, timespan

I've coded a way to display a TimeSpan in VB.NET Framework 4.0 which look like this:

```
Me.lbl_StatsOverTimeSince.Text = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(My.Settings.stats_OverTimeSince).ToString("d\d\ h\h\ m\m\ s\s")
```

Now my problem is that I tried converting this application to 2.0 and it's the only thing that is not working.

I've seen this thread: [Formatting TimeSpans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24328466/formatting-timespans)

I tried tweaking with the suggested idea:

```
Dim ts As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(My.Settings.stats_OverTimeSince)
Me.lbl_StatsOverTimeSince.Text = String.Format("{0:d\\d\\ h\\h\\ m\\m\ s\\s}", ts)
```

I figured the problem is that I'm working with TimeSpan.FromSeconds instead of New TimeSpan() because it displays 999.23:59:59 whatever the FromSeconds value is.

Is there any workaround?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The actual problem is that .Net 2.0 does not support timespan formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's got nothing to do with using `FromSeconds`.  A `TimeSpan` is a `TimeSpan`, regardless of how it was created.

The overloads of `TimeSpan.ToString` were only added in .NET 4.0.  Your use of `String.Format` is still going to rely on `TimeSpan.ToString` internally.  You'll have to do your own formatting:

```
Dim time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(My.Settings.stats_OverTimeSince)

Me.lbl_StatsOverTimeSince.Text = String.Format("{0}d {1}h {2}m {3}s", time.Days, time.Hours, time.Minutes, time.Seconds)
```

Comment: Nice one! Thanks for your quick answer! I needed that to release my new version of the app. ^_^